# change background color and text when changing state no matter the color

Tags: sass

I'd like to be able to take any div, no matter it's background color and give it a slight change in color, either darker or lighter depending on my situation

Currently, I can do it with css but then I have to pick the color. I want it for an unknown colored or white or black button.

```js
function theFunction(){
    console.log("woho");
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0; }

.button1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Lexend", sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #0084ff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease; }
  .button1.selected {
    background-color: #0077e6;
    color: white; }
  .button1:hover {
    background-color: #006acc;
    color: white; }
  .button1:active {
    background-color: #99ceff;
    color: black; }

.text {
  text-align: center; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Perfect Button</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button1" onclick="theFunction()">
    <div class="text">Click Me</div>
  </div>

  <div class="button1 selected" onclick="theFunction()">
    <div class="text">Click Me</div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it for any background color of any div use:

```
$--color: #0084ff;
$--black: black;
$--white: white;
$--background-active: ligther($--color, 30%);

body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

@mixin backgroundLigthen($--color, $--percentage) {
  background-color: lighten($--color, $--percentage);
  $--background: lighten($--color, $--percentage);
  @include adjust-text-color($--background);
}

@mixin backgroundDarken($--color, $--percentage) {
  background-color: darken($--color, $--percentage);
  $--background: darken($--color, $--percentage);
  @include adjust-text-color($--background);
}

@mixin adjust-text-color($--background) {
  @if (lightness($--background) < 50%) {
    color: $--white;
  } @else {
    color: $--black;
  }
}

.button1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 130px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Lexend", sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: $--color;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  @if (lightness($--color) > 50%) {
    color: $--white;
  }

  &.selected {
    @include backgroundDarken($--color, 5%);
  }

  &:hover {
    @include backgroundDarken($--color, 10%);
  }

  &:active {
    @include backgroundLigthen($--color, 30%);
  }
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For a scss example: https://jsfiddle.net/gu2r4jqk/7/